# Compute variable initial value

Tags: spss

How can i do this in SPSS?i need to compute the variable 'Initial cash ratio, but don't know how to do this[image: I need the method for the last column]

Comment: Welcome to Stack-Overflow! Your clear examples + the expected output are very helpful to understand your question, but still an explanation would help to understand what exactly you are trying to do and how to help you. Please click EDIT under your post to add it.

Answer (score 1):

To create a variable that contains the `cash_ratio` value from the first year of every "ID_firm" we'll have to first identify the first year of every firm and then copy the value to the other years:

```
aggregate /outfile=* mode=addvariables /break ID_firm /firstyear=min(year).
if year=firstyear initial_cash_ratio=cash_ratio.
aggregate outfile=* mode=addvariables overwritevars=yes
            /break ID_firm /initial_cash_ratio=max(initial_cash_ratio).
```